# jQuery UI Dialog with Confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI dialog that gets a line of text. If this text is not contained in a localStorage dictionary, I insert it into the dictionary. If it *is* present, I want to give the user the option not to overwrite the existing entry in the "ok" handler.

Because jQuery UI dialogs are stateful and persist across multiple calls unless explicitly removed (AFAICT), I'm not seeing a clear path to presenting the "are you sure you want to nuke your previous entry?" alert without resorting to ... uh ... alert.

The question, succinctly stated: Can you create a confirmation box from inside a jQuery UI Dialog?

Thanks.

Comment: It's relatively easy to simply destroy a dialog and recreate it.  `$('selector').dialog('destroy').dialog()` will do it.  That being said I'm not even sure why it's a problem that the dialog is stateful.  You can always configure things about it such as the title and text displayed for individual calls.

Comment: The stateful nature is a problem in a client-side Web app that might want to present multiple dialogs -- and in my case, a dialog as a child of an already open dialog. Why it's a problem is that jQUI "remembers" and reuses a lot (state), creating whacked values and/or text in some cases. I can't just destroy dialog #1 because dialog #1's yes handler acts depending on the yes/no answer to dialog #2.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used jQuery UI Dialog, but you can always create your own html elements and do whatever you wish with them, including layering them on top of the jQuery dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could have googled something to find these links:

Anyways have it and make fun:

1. [JQuery Dialogs](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/)
2. [Jquery Confirmation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

Cheers!!!

Comment: I did Google and I did visit these links (which are backwards, actually -- the first points to Confirmation and the second to Dialog). The second link you posted actually points to a blog post that explains the stateful nature of jQuery Dialogs and some of the side-effects. The second is interesting, but what appeals about the jQuery UI stuff is the consistency of theme. But yes, I know how to use Google, but no, my results were not what I had hoped.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turned out the best way I found to handle this was using closures. Like this (pseudo-code):

```
getThingieName: handler(function() {
  var $dialog;
  $dialog = $('<div id="thingie-name-dialog" class="ui-widget"></div>').html("<p>Enter a name for this thingie</p>\n<input type=\"text\" id=\"dlg-thingie-name\" style=\"width: 80%\" />").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  }, {
    title: 'enter a name',
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Add: function() {
        var value = $('#dlg-thingie-name').val();
        $(this).dialog('close');
        $('#thingie-name-dialog').remove();
        return handler(value);                  // <= closure to handle the onAdd
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        return $('#thingie-name-dialog').remove();
      }
    }
  });
  return $dialog.dialog('open');
}),

getConfirmation: function(message, handler) {
  var $dialog;
  $dialog = $('<div id="confirmation-dialog" class="ui-widget"></div>').html("<p>" + message + "</p>").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  }, {
    title: 'confirm overwrite',
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        $('#confirmatio-dialog').remove();
        return handler(true);               // <= closure to handle onOk
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        $('#Thingie-name-dialog').remove();
        return handler(false);              // <= closure to handle onCancel
      }
    }
  });
  return $dialog.dialog('open');
}

// Calling sequence
Snippets.getSnippetName(function(value) {
  if (value == null) return false;
  if (localStorage.getItem(value)) {
    getConfirmation("This thingie, " + value + ", already exists. Overwrite?", function(response) {
      if (response) return localStorage.setItem(value, snippet);
    });
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem(value, snippet);
  }
}
```

This may not be the optimal code, but it does make the triggering of the dialogs dependent on the button push by embedding them in the handlers.